# Fullscreen Causes AttributeError in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

This is an odd little thing.  I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2 (brew build on OSX 10.7), cv2 bindings, and going by the OpenCV documentation, I've tried both:

```
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

Both return that cv2 doesn't have this attribute.  I assume they just haven't been added to the cv2 bindings yet.  Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there's only `cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` attribute available. To use `FULLSIZE` attribute, you need to use `cv2.cv`module.

```
cv2.setWindowProperty("Image", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Mostly right, though there was one small edit to your answer.  Instead of cv2.cv.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN, I needed cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN.

Where in the documentation did you find this and how do you see which attributes are actually available?

Comment: I use IPython, so when you press tab button, it shows all the available attributes.